# How do I find a constant k that would result in a valid PDF?

Tags: integration, density-function, multiple-integral

So given the function:

$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 k[20-x-y]&\text{if}\, x > 0, y > 0, x + y < 20\\
      0 x&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

I know how to set up the equation using the double integrals, I just don't know what the bounds would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0<x<20$ and $0<y<20-x$, so
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dy dx =\int_0^{20}\int_0^{20-x} k[20-x-y] dy dx$$

Comment: Thanks, When I get the final answer for k and substitute it back, If i integrat in respect to x would the restrictions of x in the piecewise function still be $0<x<20$? because if I do that, my probability of this marginal density function is 0.

Comment: Yes, range of $X$ is $0<x<20$. Are you sure that marginal density function that you obtained is right? You do not show any calculations.

Comment: So I got $k=\frac{3}{4000}$, plugged that into the formula to get $\frac{3}{4000}[20-x-y]$. integrated as so to get $\int\limits_0^{20}\frac{3}{4000}[20-x-y] dy = \frac{-3x-15}{50}$ which is what I have for the marginal density function

Comment: Yes, $k=\frac{3}{4000}$. In order to find marginal density of $X$, you should integrate it over all possible $y$. And for any $x\in(0,20)$, the range of $y$ is $0<y<20-x$, so $f_X(x)=\int_0^{20-x} f(x,y) dy$ for every $x\in(0,20)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I'd be screwed for my exam you're a life saver!

Comment: Good luck on the exam!